# Escape a from User targeted Cell in Excel

Tags: python, excel, com, win32com

With Python and win32com lib i write data in a continuously running excel workbook. Once in a while it needs to do some edit "by hand". When I forgot to jump out of the cell and the cursor is still blinking inside, the Python Script stop working with this error:

```
\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 541, in EnsureDispatch
raise TypeError("This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object") 
TypeError: This COM object can not automate the makepy process - please run makepy manually for this object
```

for causing that error it just needs the "Standard" lines and any cell
edit.
Example:

```
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\PyWin32.xlsx')
ws = wb.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

ws.Cells(2, 2).Value = 123
```

[image]

Is there a way to detect this matter by Python and let it get the cursor out?

Comment: Without your Python code it is tricky to suggest an answer.

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: Line 2 `excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')`